# Is there somenthing like Corona LUT to use in Blender?

Tags: lut

Is there a simple way to achieve Corona LUT results in Blender?
Where can I find sample LUTs and how could I use them on a single image rendered in Blender?
I don't want to use it in Photoshop or other softwares, I wanted to try different LUTs while still in Blender, mainly after 3.5 version improved so much compositor speed.